# CentOS: revert python version back to original

Tags: python, centos, centos-5

I installed python 2.6 using the instructions [here](http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2008/11/10/setup-python-25-mod_wsgi-and-django-10-on-centos-5-cpanel/) on CentOS 5.4. However I realized it was a bad move and I need to revert back to 2.4, which was there originally. Can anyone guide me on how to undo what I did here? In particular, I am not sure how to undo this:

Configure ld to find your shared libs:

$ cat >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opt-python2.5.conf
/opt/python2.5/lib (hit enter)
(hit ctrl-d to return to shell)
$ ldconfig

I tried removing the alias and the symlink and even re-aliasing python to /usr/bin/python, but when I try to install an RPM i get this error:

error: Failed dependencies:
   libpython2.4.so.1.0 is needed by ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Python packages from [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/) and force an install as follows:

```
rpm -Uvh --force python-*.i386.rpm
```

And for pete's sake, next time build from source and use `make altinstall`.

Comment: That or use a proper prefix - one should not be changing stuff in /usr/bin anyway.

Comment: Among other issues, remember that Yum depends on system python in CentOS.